# ¿Cómo contar correctamente las repeticiones de una substring dentro de una string en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

es que quiero contar las repeticiones que tiene la palabra ANA en la palabra BANANA.
Al usar count, solo me cuenta 1, pero son dos, ¿algún consejo?

Explicación de código y problema: Este es mi código, donde lo que hago es identificar las vocales y así poder iniciar todas las substrings con esas vocales que saco. Luego, cuento las ocurrencias de esas substrings con count y para que no se repitan las meto en una lista llamada palabrasFormadas_j2. Entre esas, sale la substring ANA y con count solo me cuenta 1 ocurrencia, pero en BANANA se repite dos veces como pueden ver.

```
posicion=0
for letra in string:
    if es_vocal(letra):
        if not letra in vocales:
            vocales.append([letra, posicion])
    posicion+=1
for vocal in vocales:
    palabra_j2=""
    nueva_string=string[vocal[1]:]
    for letra in nueva_string:
        palabra_j2=palabra_j2+letra
        if not palabra_j2 in palabrasFormadas_j2:
            palabrasFormadas_j2.append(palabra_j2)
            puntos=string.count(palabra_j2)         
            score_j2+=puntos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución simple:

```
def contar(texto, palabra):
    cuenta = 0
    len_sub = len(palabra)

    for i in range(len(texto) - len_sub + 1):
        if texto[i:i+len_sub] == palabra:
            cuenta += 1

    return cuenta
```

El procedimiento es simple: recorremos el texto de izquierda a derecha y en cada posición comparamos un pedazo contra la palabra deseada, y agregamos 1 al contar en caso de éxito.

#### Demo

```
def contar(texto, palabra):
    cuenta = 0
    len_sub = len(palabra)

    for i in range(len(texto) - len_sub + 1):
        if texto[i:i+len_sub] == palabra:
            cuenta += 1

    return cuenta

print(contar("BANANANA", 'ANA'))
```

produce:

```
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
# Initialising string
ini_str = "BANANA"
sub_str = 'ANA'

# Count count of substrings using re.findall
res = len(re.findall('(?=ANA)', ini_str))
```

Lo logré solucionar con esto que encontré en la siguiente página :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-count-number-of-substring-in-string/